# Find system log entry for Windows 7 password reminder

Tags: windows-7, logging

Is there a system log entry or something similar that will allow me to see when the Windows 7 password reminder popped up?

There are a few users who complain that it never pops up to remind them to change their password (ours is required to be reset monthly). Rather than dismiss this outright, I would like to be able to prove or disprove that they are seeing the reminder.

Comment: Have them restart the computer once a week.   Windows 7 is different then past versions.  If you don't refresh by logging out and logging back in you sometimes won't see the password reminders ( its not actually shown at all ).

Comment: @Ramhound is there a way to configure Windows7 to force them to change the password, instead of relying on a log off event?

Comment: @Moab: Use the Group Policy "Network security: Force logoff when logon hours expire" and disallow logins on sunday 3AM.

Comment: BTW, Windows 7 warns 5 days in advance, not 14.

Comment: Also, it's a balloon tip, so if balloon tips are disabled you won't see them.